# SQL sorting date by year and month

Tags: sql, pgadmin

```
SELECT ShopOrder.OrderDate
, Book.BookID
, Book.title
, COUNT(ShopOrder.ShopOrderID) AS "Total number of order"
, SUM (Orderline.Quantity) AS "Total quantity"
, Orderline.UnitSellingPrice * Orderline.Quantity  AS "Total order value"
, book.Price * Orderline.Quantity AS "Total retail value" 
      FROM ShopOrder
      JOIN Orderline
        ON Orderline.ShopOrderID = ShopOrder.ShopOrderID
      JOIN Book
        ON Book.BookID = Orderline.BookID 
      JOIN Publisher
        ON Publisher.PublisherID = Book.PublisherID
     WHERE Publisher.name = 'Addison Wesley'
     GROUP 
        BY ShopOrder.OrderDate
, Book.BookID
, Book.title
, Orderline.UnitSellingPrice
, Orderline.Quantity, book.Price 
, Orderline.Quantity, ShopOrder.ShopOrderID
     ORDER
        BY ShopOrder.OrderDate
```

[Please look at the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3s8E.png)

I want the query OrderDate group by year and month, so the data for the same month could be added together

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the year and month from the date and use those in the `select` and `group by` columns.  How you do this depends highly on the database.  Many support functions called `year()` and `month()`.

Then you need to just aggregate by the fields that you want.  Something like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(so.OrderDate) as yyyy, MONTH(so.OrderDate) as mm,      
       b.BookID, b.title,
       COUNT(so.ShopOrderID) AS "Total number of order",
       SUM(ol.Quantity) AS "Total quantity",
       SUM(ol.UnitSellingPrice * ol.Quantity  AS "Total order value",
       SUM(b.Price * ol.Quantity) AS "Total retail value" 
FROM ShopOrder so JOIN
     Orderline ol
     ON ol.ShopOrderID = so.ShopOrderID JOIN
     Book b
     ON b.BookID = ol.BookID JOIN
     Publisher p
     ON p.PublisherID = b.PublisherID
WHERE p.name = 'Addison Wesley'
GROUP BY YEAR(so.OrderDate), MONTH(so.OrderDate), b.BookID, b.title
ORDER BY MIN(so.OrderDate)
```

Note the use of table aliases makes the query easier to write and to read.

The above works in MySQL, DB2, and SQL Server.  In Postgres and Oracle, `to_char(so.OrderDate, 'YYYY-MM')`.

Comment: If I am using PGAdmin III? As it said  function year(date) does not exist

Comment: pgadmin is for Postgres.  Use `to_char(so.OrderDate, 'YYYY-MM')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For group, you can use datepart function

```
GROUP BY (DATEPART(yyyy, ShopOrder.OrderDate), DATEPART(mm, ShopOrder.OrderDate))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should aggregate

```
, Orderline.UnitSellingPrice * Orderline.Quantity  AS "Total order value"
, book.Price * Orderline.Quantity AS "Total retail value"
```

or you will have all you `count(...)` values equals to 1.
`YEAR(myDate)` and `MONTH(myDate)` for `group by` are convenient shortcuts to `datepart` function (on MS SQL Server)